# Titanium Flip animation for Android

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have superview (flashcardView ), i added the two subviews(frontView and backView) to this view. If user tap the any one of the view it flip and shows the other view. I am using the following code for achieve this functionality.

```
frontView.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

            var animation = require('alloy/animation');

            animation.flip( frontView,backView, 'horizontal',500, function(){
                    });

        });

backView.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

             var animation = require('alloy/animation');

                animation.flip( backView,frontView, 'horizontal',500, function(){
            });
```

This code is only working in iOS devices. It is not working in Android devices. Pls suggest me to do the flip animation for Android.

Comment: You can do it with the help of module

Comment: Pls provide the links for access those modules.

Comment: @Anub Try the widget http://gitt.io/component/is.decup.widget.flip  git : https://github.com/balanza/is.decup.widget.flip/tree/master/is.decup.widget.flip

Answer (score 0):

In Titanium available animations depend on the system (iOS or Android) you use. Therefore the code you use is only working for iOS. As far as I know there is no built-in flip animation for Android. But there is a solution by another user he gave in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8308773/2439890).

Here is the code he uses:

```
var anim_minimize = Titanium.UI.createAnimation({width:0,duration:500});
var anim_maximize = Titanium.UI.createAnimation({width:320,duration:500});

tabGroup.animate(anim_minimize);

setTimeout(function(){

tabGroup.animate(anim_maximize);

},500);
```

Basically he creates the views next to each other and uses another animation which should look the same as a flip animation.

Another option you could try is using a module such as [Flipium](https://github.com/wongpeiyi/flipium).